# How to execute macros

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to execute this simple macro but it won't execute. After clicking on the `.docm` file I click on `enable content` but no macro gets executed.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "Welcome to Excel! This macro is running automatically."
End Sub
```

How can I make sure the macro is executed after clicking on `enable content`?

Comment: Workbook_Open won't do anything when you open a *Word document*. To get something to happen automatically when you do that you would usually need to put some Word VBA code in the Word Document or its associated Template and you would use another event (e.g. Document_Open).

Answer (score 0):

Just reopen it. Because *Workbook_Open()* this event will only be triggered when the/a Workbook is opened.

Or you in the VBE, to run it. Just place the cursor in the code, then [press key F8 (step by step) or F5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/menu-shortcut-keys-available-in-the-code-window) to run it. (There are corresponding buttons and options in the [toolbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/debug-toolbar) and [menu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/debug-menu)).